# MySQL: DELETE FROM with information from a subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, delete-row

I have a table delete_requests where I store the id's for delete requests for the entries of my users table. Is it possible to delete from users with the information from delete_requests as a condition?

My problem is, that the result set will usually not be limited to one row but return several.

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE id=(SELECT id FROM delete_requests)
```

So MySQL complains:

```
#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Can this be done in one statement without putting the logic into the executing application?

Comment: it should,because of you are not restricting the subquery to fetch specific record it's fetching all records and **=** means you are looking only for a single match.

Comment: did you tried with id IN (subquery) rather id =

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the IN clause

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM delete_requests)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the in clause.

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM delete_requests)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM delete_requests)
```